# Text is blurry on Safari and am able to type on it

Tags: css, cross-browser, mobile-safari

I have a website and it has a contact form on home page made with contact form 7 plugin. In Mobile view I am not able to click on the form controls. The letters on the text filled is also blurry. I do not have an iPhone, but it's not looking good in the Safari browser.

Website : tinyurl.com/z62tt72

I've tried the CSS below but I still am not able to click on Name Filed.

```
* { 
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
*:not(input.field) {    
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
input, textarea {
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif ! ;  
    font-size:large !important;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -khtml-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: It seems text is too small to read or write, am i right??

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

> Some font files contain additional information about how the font
>   should be rendered. `optimizeLegibility` makes use of this
>   information.

or another trick i've used in the past for font rendering is:

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
```

the RGB would be the font colour, the opacity would stay the same.

Comment: text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; making all of my font junk character also in iphone i cannot type in it

Comment: That sounds very weird - Did you generate the font yourself?